# why ID is not defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

When i send DELETE request i got message error
`ReferenceError: id is not defined`
`at Object.removeOne (...\services\user.js:16:38`

I have no idea what id about in \services\user.js, and why it is not defined...

**./generalRepository.js**

```
function Repository() {}
Repository.prototype.findAndRemoveById = findAndRemoveById;

function findAndRemoveById(id, callback) {
  var model = this.model;
  var query = model.deleteOne({
    _id: id
  });
  query.exec(callback);
}

module.exports = Repository;
```

**.routers/user.js**

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const userService = require("../../services/user");

router.delete("/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  userService.removeOne(String(req.params.id), (err, data) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.send('success delete query');
    } else {
      console.log("wrong delete query");
      res.status(400);
      res.end();
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**.services/user.js**

```
const UserRepository = require("../repositories/UserRepository");

module.exports = {
  removeOne: () => {
    UserRepository.findAndRemoveById(id, (err, data) => {
      callback(err, data);
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: `removeOne` should take `id` as argument, which will eventually get passed to `findAndRemoveById`

Comment: you are requiring UserRepository, but you have defined findAndRemoveById in generalRepository.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update `removeOne` function to following by expecting arguments (`id` and `callback`) to be passed when it is being called.

```
const UserRepository = require("../repositories/UserRepository");

module.exports = {
  removeOne: (id, callback) => {
    UserRepository.findAndRemoveById(id, (err, data) => {
      callback(err, data);
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should be like this:

```
module.exports = {
  removeOne: (id) => {
    UserRepository.findAndRemoveById(id, (err, data) => {
     callback(err, data);
    });
  }
};
```